# Can we calculate moment of Inertia of the picture given below?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, biophysics, moment-of-inertia

[image]

So one half of this picture is formed of a broad , more or less Triangular bony plate , called scapulo-coracoid and a small clavicle bone.
I m interested in biomimcry and I want to know the hidden technical knowledge behind this work of nature.  I know how to derive MOI for spherical shape , cylindrical shape. But I m not able to get my head around this one .

Comment: @Benjamin Schroeder " one half of this picture is formed of a  broad , more or less Triangular bony plate , called scapulo-coracoid and a small clavicle bone " . This is information given about the shape of this thing. If by  " mathematical definition of the body " you mean radius , length , breadth of this thing , we can assume R , L and B as radius , length and breadth resp.

Comment: -1 No research effort. How have you tried to calculate the moment of inertia for this object? ... What use to you is a value for the MOI of this bone?

Comment: @sammygerbil right now just for the sake of curiosity .

Answer (score 1):

No. If you don't have a mathematical definition of the body we cannot calculate its moment of inertia.

If you had a physical specimen, you could try mounting it along the axis you want to measure and measuring the response to a torque.